# code not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please find the code to generate

```
 <style>
text.shadow {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 2.5px;
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

I have code attached which should display

Comment: Can you please check your code? It has syntax issues and you are using variables that are not defined in the given code such as `newDataArray`? When posting on SO, please try to post code that can be run by others to find the mistake.

Comment: you fancy attaching your css, I've made a fiddle but it needs styling

Comment: got it working now : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/o5kwgb7x/1/ is there any more css ?

Comment: You have just overwritten all your code with css

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct data. You have this function :

```
 function mousemove() {
         var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
           i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
           d0 = newDataArray[i - 1],
           d1 = newDataArray[i],
           d = x0 - d0.i > d1.i - x0 ? d1 : d0;
         focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.i) + "," + y(d.fit) + ")");
         focus.select("text").text(Math.floor(d.fit));
       }
```

On line 3, you are using `data`. Where is `data` ? It should be `newDataArray` right ?

Also this should come up in the console log, do you read the console log when developing ?

Right, you have this function :

```
function mousemove() {
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
                i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                d0 = newDataArray[i-1],
                d1 = newDataArray[i],   
                d = x0 - d0.i > d1.i - x0 ? d1 : d0;
            focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.i) + "," + y(d.fit) + ")");
            focus.select("text").text(Math.floor(d.fit));
        }
```

This won't run at all. You're passing `d.i` and `d.fit` to `x` and `y` axis. What is d.i ? It doesn't exist in your data.

I have put together this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/o5kwgb7x/3/

Your `mousemove` function wont work as your not translating the focus (circle) properly. What id `d.i` ?  What you need to do is pass it what you are using as the y axis, so in this case, d.fit like so :

```
d = x0 - d0.fit > d1.fit - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

And then you translate it, `d.upr` in the x and `d.fit` in the y. Full mousemove function :

```
function mousemove() {
   var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]), 
     i = bisectDate(newDataArray, x0, 1), 
     d0 = newDataArray[i - 1], 
     d1 = newDataArray[i], 
     d = x0 - d0.fit > d1.fit - x0 ? d1 : d0; 

   focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.upr) + "," + y(d.fit) + ")"); 
   focus.select("text").text(Math.floor(d.fit));
 }
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/o5kwgb7x/5/

I take it you got the example from here : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569

Here is a breakdown of how this works. Read and understand what it is doing before doing more things to your view. It's best to understand it all otherwise youll just get stuck. TIP: use the console log!

Comment: However this still doesn't work. I'll try find the problem, is there anymore css on this  ?

Comment: I've edited my question, you have some errors in your code and I dont know why you put them there. Are you just copying from an example ? Do you debug via console ?

Comment: obviously its not logging an error as Ive passed it an acatual value. I passed 'i', which is 1, so it's always going to be 1. And that shows that.

Comment: Different question. Also you need to update the code in your question. You have overwritten it

Comment: all you have created is a circle. You haven't appended any value

Comment: I recommend you read through your code and look at examples. It looks like your just mashing your code up with another and asking us why it doesnt work without doing anywork yourself.

Comment: all it takes is adding that one line, really ? Im sorry but stop being lazy and look at the changes I have made. I forgot to add that line back in, would have taken 30 seconds to realise : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/o5kwgb7x/5/

Comment: I'm seeing to this now